# Does Spring rollback on Runtime Exception when rollback for checked exception is specified in @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Given following `@Transactional` annotation defined on a class.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = CheckedException.class)
```

Will Spring still Rollback on thrown Unchecked (`Runtime`) exception plus the `CheckedException.class`? Or given the above annotation, will it rollback **only** for the listed Exceptions,i.e., `CheckedException.class` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any runtime exception will always cause rollback, whether you mention a checked exception in rollbackFor or not.